# xCode Profile: there are errors when profiling, but there is none when running

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, profile

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Errors Of GData occurs when profiling my app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12156593/errors-of-gdata-occurs-when-profiling-my-app)

The issue is told in the title. I am wondering whether it is ok for my app submission to app store as some files only linked dynamically. Can anyone give me some advice?

Comment: @PaulR as shown here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12156593/errors-of-gdata-occurs-when-profiling-my-app

Comment: Don't ask the same question twice: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12156593/errors-of-gdata-occurs-when-profiling-my-app

Comment: delete the project from simulator, clean it and build it again

Comment: Make sure you're running and profiling the same build by checking Product->Edit Scheme

Comment: @SurvivalMachine I'm sure they're the same.:)

Comment: @AdeelPervaiz  Happening to a strange issue, cleaning is often my first choice. But this time cleaning doesn't help.